# How to format output from nmap in a specific predefined format

Tags: text-processing, nmap

Assume I am executing nmap shell to find out a simple output.We are all familiar with this one:

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at.... 
Nmap scan report for www.google.com (172.217.26.68)
Host is up (0.085s latency).
rDNS record for 172.217.26.68: sin10s02-in-f68.1e100.net
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 9.38 seconds
```

Now I want the port state and service specifically
For example:

```
Open ports are:
80
443
```

or something like this.The point is I want to use a specific output and use it somewhere else.Can anyone give me a very very simple example?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'Open ports are:';nmap localhost -oG -|grep -oP '[0-9]*(?=/open)'
Open ports are:
22
6000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
echo "Open ports are: ";nmap $HOST |awk -F'/' '/open/ {print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your_nmap_cmd |
sed -ne '
  /^PORT/!d
  h;n              # grab PORT line & prepare for port info
  \|/|!q           # we are done once no / found so quitting
  s|/.* open .*||p # display port num only for open state
  G;D              # without reading next input goto top
'
```